# I had to report to the police

Tags: grammar, tense

Context:

> I sent money to buy a second hand iphone 5s from him but he just whatsapped me the picture of DHL receipt and told me he that he had already sent out the parcel.
>   I tracked the tracking number only to find the entry - 'HASN'T RECORDED.'
>   I called him but he never answered my call nor did he return it afterwards. He continued to sell iphones via the facebook group for the last few days.
>   Now ***I had to report to the  police***. If anyone have details of this phony guy pls inform me.

Do we use ***had*** or ***have*** when stating that the report have been made just few hours ago?

Comment: I think it should be "I *have reported* (the case to the) police". The original sentence is not grammatically sound.

Comment: "I had to" = "It became necessary for me to." That's how it should be. Also, "Now" = consequently, because of this, therefore. HTH.

Comment: The original sentence is grammatically fine. "At the moment referred to, I had an obligation to report to the police". See [ODO](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now) at #6 for a reference to _now_ referring to the past.

Comment: @user73963: can you please clarify if the report has been filed or not yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If reporting to the police has already happened, *had* is the correct form: there was a moment in the past when you were obliged to report to the police, but since you have already reported to them, the obligation no longer exists, so using a present tense would be confusing.

If the reporting to the police has **not** happened yet, the obligation exists at the moment of speaking, so a present tense would make that very clear.

**Note** that "if anyone *have*" is ungrammatical: *anyone* is third person, so it should be *if anyone **has***.

In short:

> Now I **had** to report to the police.

In the *past*, there **was** an obligation to report to the police. I have already reported to the police. For anyone confused about the use of *now* when referring to the past, have a look at [ODO](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now) which has a nice example under #6: *now the trouble began*.

> Now I **have** to report to the police.

At *present*, there **is** an obligation to report to the police. I have not reported to the police yet.

Asking for information about the guy hints that the speaker *has not yet reported* to the police, as he probably wants to include any extra information in the report to file with the police. On the other hand, "if the report **has** been made just **a** few hours ago", then *has* is the correct form. It really depends on the fact of the situation, which we do not know — we get conflicting information!

Comment: I really don’t understand how can go in English *now* with *had*.

Comment: @LucianSava: there is no problem with that at all. _Now_ can mean "at the time referred to", see this [ODO reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now) at #6: "now the trouble began".

Comment: And here again, I wonder: why the downvote?

Comment: thank you for your explanation, as for the downvote it wasn't I. Perhaps my comment attracted it and I'm very sory for that.

Comment: @LucianSava: don't worry about it :) Your remark was legit, if people think downvoting is a good idea without explaining why they do it, that is not your fault :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already reported him

> Now I have had to report him to the police

(Although the "now" makes it more of a colloquialism, the text appears to be from a forum or Facebook page, so it would be suitable)

Or

> I have reported him to the police

---

If you haven't yet reported him

> Now I have to report him to the police

Answer (score 0):

"Had to" here is not a tense identifier but is being used with another meaning, "was forced to". ("Forced" here meaning forced by circumstances, not that someone put a gun to my head.) "I had reported it" is putting the act of reporting in the past perfect, that is "I reported" but in the past perfect. "I had to report it" is the simple past tense, meaning "I was forced to report it."

"Now" here does not mean "at the present time", but "because of this circumstance." For example you could write, "Caesar crossed the Rubicon. Now the Roman Senate was placed in a difficult position." The "now" here does not mean that the Roman Senate is in a difficult position in 2014, but rather that the event described in the previous sentence led to this result.

Technicality: The sentence should read, "Now I had to report IT to the police." The verb "report" without an object generally means "to present oneself" or "to be accountable to". Like if you say, "I must report to the army", that is usually understood to mean that you volunteered or were drafted and now you must show up. Sometimes we say, "Bob reported to the committee" meaning "he presented information to the committee", but this is relatively rare and I have never heard the word "report" used this way with respect to the police. When you want to say that someone called the police to tell them that a crime was committed, you say, "He reported THE CRIME to the police", "Bob called the police to report A MURDER", etc.